# Specificity? "High-Contrast and spectroscopic-based specificity of optical imaging."

Tags: optics

I came across the following phrase:

> High-Contrast and spectroscopic-based specificity of optical imaging.

I'm wondering what is meant by "specificity" in this context?

Thanks for any clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Medical lingo "**Sensitivity**" ( refers to targets) and "**Specificity**" refers to the opposite or **insensitivity** to non-targets or make invisible or transparent, such as body plasma, thus resulting in better contrast ratio imaging.

For example, since blood is red, infrared tends to make it white or invisible as opposed to dark in a monochrome image. Thus the light spectrum is insensitive to that or in this example spectral reflection of the similar wavelengths of light.

Comment: But I don’t think that makes sense in this context?

Comment: optical contrast depends on the specific wavelength for transmission and reflection  i.e. spectroscopic-based specificity of optical imaging.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a EE question...

The full sentence is:

> It is a hybrid modality, combining the high-contrast and
>   spectroscopic-based specificity of optical imaging with the high
>   spatial resolution of ultrasound imaging.

Specificity means " high-contrast " specific advantage of optical imaging.

Could be reworded as

> It is a hybrid modality, combining the high-contrast advantage of
>   spectroscopic-based  optical imaging with the advantage of high
>   spatial resolution of ultrasound imaging.

Basically taking the good specific part of two methods integrated in one system.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=High-Contrast+and+spectroscopic-based+specificity+of+optical+imaging.&oq=High-Contrast+and+spectroscopic-based+specificity+of+optical+imaging.

Comment: I think here "specificity" does not mean "high contrast" but the ability to identify different molecules from there optical properties. Like "this absorption pattern definitly belongs to hemoglobin".

Comment: @jusaca You mean as in Sunnyskyguy's answer?